# Can someone tell me what's wrong with my dropdown menu javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been learning Javascript and as a bit of practice, thought i'd create myself a dropdown navigation menu, that works on a 'click' rather than hover. I've created the code below (which doesn't work) and i was wondering if someone could explain why so i can see where i've gone wrong.

I can get the dropdown to open, but when i added the code to close the dropdown, the dropdown menu doesn't even open.

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction so i can see where i'm going wrong and i can avoid such issues in the future

```js
(function() {
  let menuHeader = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item-has-children');
  let subMenu = document.querySelector('.sub-menu');
  menuHeader.forEach(function(btn) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      subMenu.classList.add('nav-open');
      // Close if anywhere on screen aprt form menu is clicked
      if (subMenu.classList.contains('nav-open')) {
        window.onclick = function(event) {
          if (!event.target.classList.contains('sub-menu')) {
            subMenu.classList.remove('nav-open');
          }
        };
      };
    });
  });


})();
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="" title="Home">Home</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#" title="What We Do">What We Do</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="" title="">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="">Page 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="">Page 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=" ">Page 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="">Page 6</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#" title="Our Work">Our Work</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="" title="">Portfolio 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="">Portfolio 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="">Portfolio 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="">Portfolio 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="">Portfolio 5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

As requested, the CSS is as follows

```
.main-nav ul > li   {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}


.main-nav ul li  a  {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: bebas-neue, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    padding: 0.5em 0.8em 0.8em 0.8em;
    transition: background 0.2s linear;
}

.main-nav ul li  a:hover    {
    background: #00a492;
    color: #fff;
}

.main-nav ul li a:not(:only-child):after {
    content: '\25bc';
    font-size: 0.6em;
    position: relative;
    top: -4px;
    left: 2px;
}



/* Second Level of Navigation */

.main-nav ul li  ul {
    width: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 160%;
    left: 0;
    background: #00a492;
}

.main-nav ul li  ul li a    {
    display: block;
}

.sub-menu   {
    display: none;
}

.nav-open   {
    display: block;
}

.slicknav_menu {
    display:none;
}

.highlight-btn  {
    background: #00a492 !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

``

Comment: Can you show the CSS also ? It can be a problem in there too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using event delegation instead. When anywhere on the page is clicked, run an event listener. If the clicked target is not inside a LI, remove the `.nav-open` from the existing element with `.nav-open`, if there is one. Otherwise, if the clicked target was the `<a>` (a descendant of the outer `.menu-item-has-children`), navigate to its second child (`.children[1]`) and add the class to it:

```js
function closeOpenNav() {
  const currentOpen = document.querySelector('.nav-open');
  if (currentOpen) {
    currentOpen.classList.remove('nav-open');
  }
}

window.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const li = event.target.closest('.menu-item-has-children');
  if (!li) {
    // Close if anywhere on screen aprt form menu is clicked
    console.log('closing');
    closeOpenNav();
    return;
  }
  if (event.target.parentElement !== li) {
    // The clicked element is a descendant of a `.nav-open`
    // so, don't do anything
    return;
  }
  event.preventDefault();
  closeOpenNav();
  const thisSubMenu = li.children[1];
  thisSubMenu.classList.add('nav-open');
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}
.nav-open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="" title="Home">Home</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#" title="What We Do">What We Do</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="" title="">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="">Page 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="">Page 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=" ">Page 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="">Page 6</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#" title="Our Work">Our Work</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="" title="">Portfolio 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="">Portfolio 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="">Portfolio 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="">Portfolio 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="">Portfolio 5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it can happen because at first you are adding `nav-open` class than you are checking is it exist if yes you are adding event to window(window still can catch this event) and deleting this class so nothing should happen. Try to add`event.stopPropagation()` under `event.preventDefault()`

````
(function() {
  let menuHeader = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item-has-children');
  let subMenu = document.querySelector('.sub-menu');
  menuHeader.forEach(function(btn) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation()
      subMenu.classList.add('nav-open');
      // Close if anywhere on screen aprt form menu is clicked
      if (subMenu.classList.contains('nav-open')) {
        window.onclick = function(event) {
          if (!event.target.classList.contains('sub-menu')) {
            subMenu.classList.remove('nav-open');
          }
        };
      };
    });
  });


})();```
````

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking time out to comment. I tried this and it looked like it was working well, however, it only opens the first sub-menu so doesn't work.

Comment: Probably because ```subMenu``` is array so you are applying it only for first element of ```subMenu``` array ;)

Comment: If you want to have this behavior on all of your ```subMenu``` elements you have to iterate over ```subMenu``` array ;)

Comment: Thank you. As you can probably tell i'm very much a beginner with this. :-)

Answer (score 0):

maybe like so, code should be self explanatory

```js
// Dropdown Menu
    (function(){
      let menuHeader = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item-has-children');
      menuHeader.forEach(function(btn){
        btn.addEventListener('click', function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          
          if(this.classList.contains('nav-open')) {
              return this.classList.remove('nav-open');
          }
          
          var openNavPoints = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item-has-children.nav-open');
          if(openNavPoints.length >= 1) {
              [...openNavPoints].forEach(function(openNavPoint) {
                  openNavPoint.classList.remove('nav-open');
              });
          }
          this.classList.add('nav-open');
          
        });
      });
    })();
```

```css
.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu {
    display: none;
}
.menu-item-has-children.nav-open .sub-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav">
<ul>
        <li><a href="" title="Home">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#" title="What We Do">What We Do</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="" title="">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="" title="">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="" title="">Page 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="" title="">Page 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="" title=" ">Page 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="" title="">Page 6</a></li>
            </ul></li>
        <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#" title="Our Work">Our Work</a>
            <ul  class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="" title="">Portfolio 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="" title="">Portfolio 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="" title="">Portfolio 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="" title="">Portfolio 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="" title="">Portfolio 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="" title="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but this didn't work i'm afraid

Comment: @Ross what do you mean "it didn't work"? you want it to colapse if open? I've updated the answer now also working for "toggle" (collapse if open)

Comment: Hi, the menu doesn't close when i click on the screen. It;s no problem though as i have it sorted now. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is a wroking demo

```js
(function() {
  let menuHeader = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item-has-children');
  let subMenus = document.querySelectorAll('.sub-menu');
  menuHeader.forEach(function(btn) {
    btn.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
   event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      closeAllMenus();
      btn.querySelector('.sub-menu').classList.add('nav-open');
    });
  });

  document.addEventListener("click", function(){
   closeAllMenus();
  });
  
  function closeAllMenus(){
   subMenus.forEach(function(ele) {
     ele.classList.remove('nav-open');
    });
  }


})();
```

```css
.sub-menu{
  display: none;
}
.sub-menu.nav-open{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="" title="Home">Home</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children">
      <a href="#" title="What We Do">What We Do</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="" title="">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="">Page 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="">Page 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title=" ">Page 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="">Page 6</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#" title="Our Work">Our Work</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="" title="">Portfolio 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="">Portfolio 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="">Portfolio 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="">Portfolio 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="" title="">Portfolio 5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

The first mistake on your code was declaring this

```
let subMenu = document.querySelector('.sub-menu');
```

this always will be the first subMenu, so I just removed it.
If you want to get the subMenu of every element you should do something like this:

```
btn.querySelector('.sub-menu')
```

So now It will get the sub menu for every element inside the forEach you already did.

---

To close the menu on document click I just made an event listener on document click which will remove the class `nav-open` from any of the sub menus.

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(){
    subMenus.forEach(function(ele) {
        ele.classList.remove('nav-open');
    });
  });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking time out to explain where i was going wrong. The code you suggested worked in respect of opening/closing the menus but i didn;t like how it left multiple menus open at the same time. I really appreciate your help though

Comment: I just edited the code and added a function that close all the opened submenus so you can use it where ever you want. check it.